# Google app engine python Database losing data

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Using the python google app engine datastore on localhost, every now and then all the data will be lost. When it happens, every time my google app engine launcher will freeze and I have to force quit to restart it. Anyone know why and have the same problem? How can I get it fix?

Running on: Macbook Pro Version 10.7.5
Operating System: Lion
Language: python

Google App Engine SDK: Version 1.7.5
I think the server is: dev_appserver since the log console uses dev_appserver.py

and I'm Using the launcher.

Comment: Please add more information like which runtime you're using (Java|Python|go), where do you put the local db file, and what is your operating software, etc.

Comment: What is your sdk version?
Are you using devappserver2?
What is the command line? or are you using launcher?

Comment: please see the above, I edited the post.